# Change hidden field value everytime marker position is changed on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am making a google maps application in which i allow a user to place only one marker on the map by clicking on the map. Everytime the user click again on the map, the old marker is deleted and the marker is placed on the new click location. I have a hidden input field and i want the its value to change each time the marker changes position. This value should be the coordinates of the new marker location. The code i have written for this is as follows,

```
var map;
var marker;
var coords;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.074448,72.872314);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
};

function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker = null;
        placeMarker(location);
    }
    else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
            });
        document.getElementById("id_lat").value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue()
    }
};
```

Specifically, i am using this line to change the value,

```
document.getElementById("id_lat").value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue()
```

where the id of the relevant hidden field is "id_lat"
This doesn't seem to work though. What am i doing wrong and how do i fix it ? I am new to javascript.

Comment: You could try to find the error message. So, it's help to solve the issue very quickly. Please use try { docu... = marker.getPosi... } catch (e) { alert (e.message); } and post the alert message here.

Comment: @Mr. Black - I tried it. It didnt show any alert boxes or any errors in fact.

Comment: Ok, so i checked. The source of the page doesnt change. But when the form is submitted, i get the right coordinates in the submitted form data. I am fine with that too. So i guess, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add your one marker at initialize() function. Other than that your code seems to work fine.

```
var map;
var marker;
var coords;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.074448,72.872314);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
    // add a marker on map
    placeMarker(latlng);
};

function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker = null;
        placeMarker(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
        document.getElementById("id_lat").value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue();
            // worked for me for <input type="text" value="Submit" id="id_lat" style="display:none"/> element
        alert(document.getElementById("id_lat").value);
    }
};
```

Comment: yeah, its working for me too now. Didnt need to add that one marker. But i thought it would dynamically change the source code. It doesn't. However, when the form is submitted, i get the right coordinates and i am ok with that. Thanks for the help though :)